# How to prevent data loss using Application.VLookup?

Tags: excel, vba

The following macro utilizes the VLookup function between two workbooks. Both workbooks contain tables. The intent is for **book1** to update values from **book2**

The data loss (cells that have values in **book1**, column 7 gets removed) occurs whenever the lookup value is not present in **book2**. Which leads to my question: how to prevent this deletion from occurring?

```
Sub Update()
Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchRange As Range

Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim book2 As Workbook

Dim book2Name As String
book2Name = "table2.xlsm"

Dim book2NamePath As String
book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

Set book1 = ThisWorkbook

If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)
Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)

Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Range("a23:a100")
Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("b:f")

lookFor.Offset(0, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the return value and only update if there is something to return.

```
Dim val as Variant

Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Range("a23:a100")
Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("b:f")

val = Application.VLookup(lookFor.Cells(1), srchRange, 2, False)

If Not IsError(val) Then
    lookFor.Offset(0, 7).Value = val
End If
```

You can test the return to a variant with Application.VLookup or Application.Match. It has to be returned to a variant and it doesn't work with WorksheetFunction.VLookup or WorksheetFunction.Match.

Comment: This ends up being the same functionality, same bug with values not present in book1 are removed when executed.

Comment: If vlookup doesn't find a match it returns #N/A. A variant can catch an #N/A and IsError is true when val is #N/A. How could it possibly do what you are describing? Perhaps you should post the actual code as I had to modify your vlookup in order to make it work. You cannot vlookup Range("a23:a100") all at once, you have to make a lookup for each cell in Range("a23:a100").

Comment: the posted code works on my end... what did you have to modify to make it work on your end?

Comment: vlookup is meant to take a single value as its first argument. You've shoving 78 values (Range("a23:a100")) into the first argument so you are implicitly using Range("a23").

Comment: I made a huge mistake in explaining this bug... swap book1 and book2 meanings. I am using book2 as my source that I want to update from - does this make sense? sorry for the confusion... edits to original question were made